# EUler4 program acting oddly?

Tags: java

So I'm working on Project Euler problem #4 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) and wrote this code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (int i = 100000; i<999*999; i++) {
            String st=i+"";
            char char1 = st.charAt(0);
            char char2 = st.charAt(1);
            char char3 = st.charAt(2);
            char char4 = st.charAt(3);
            char char5 = st.charAt(4);
            char char6 = st.charAt(5);

            if (char1 == char5 && char2 == char5 && char3 == char4) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But whenever I run it the first number is 110010, which isn't a palindrome number, and then it prints out that number +1 until it reaches 997799, which curiously is 1 number away from where it should reach because 999*999= 998001. So my question is why does this code start with 110010, count up from 1 from there on and print it out, and then why does it end at 997799? I just don't understand how you get that printed out from my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo in the `if` statement:

```
if (char1 == char6 && ...
```